# Why does DateDiff function fail with "Invalid operation: Data value "0" has invalid format"in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a datediff() function that throws an exception.

I am trying to calculate the number of days between two dates.  The rub is that one date is a converted integer value in YYYYMMDD format and the second date field is a timestamp.  So, in the snippet below I am doing what I think are the correct conversions.  Sometimes, it runs actually.

The message I get is: Amazon Invalid operation: Data value "0" has invalid format.

```
select site, datediff(days,to_date(cast(posting_dt_sk as varchar), 'YYYYMMDD'),trunc(ship_dt)) days_to_ship from sales_table
```

Later I added a Where-clause as to ignore empty values thinking I had bad data but that's not it.  I still get the message.

```
where posting_dt_sk is not null and posting_dt_sk > 0
```

It all looks right to me, but it fails.

Comment: did you get data from mysql? do you have 0 dates? 00:00:00 i mean?

Comment: I ran some validation queries to determine every integer date was indeed YYYYMMDD format.   It's a DW system, so I trust that though the data type is integer, that it meets the correct format.  I do a trunc on the timestamp date to get rid of the time values.   I am in SQL Workbench connecting to Redshift.

Comment: can you try to find the data that is actually causing the issue?  by narrowing it down with your where clause. and then if necessary update the question with the exact data.

Comment: The data is good.... I have a Inner Join in the query that should restrict the results.  But, if I include in the Where clause a column test that the Join should manage by the successful Join, it works.   So, a redundant statement in the Where-clause gets past the error.   I don't have the option of redundant clauses.

Comment: This query runs in an Informatica job connecting to AmazonAWS.  There are inconveniences in what you can do with SQL.

Comment: im not saying put the where clause in permanently - more- just get sight of the specific data causing the issue,